# Как из схемы вытащить атрибут biography, далее поместить его значение в обьект для последующей вставки в PUG-код?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

У меня есть схема Character

```js
const characterSchema = new Schema({
    desc: String,
    tag: String,
    info: String,
    creator: String,
    state: Object,
    account: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        index: true,
        ref: 'Account'
    },
    site: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Auth'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    flags: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    lastUsed: {
        type: Date,
        index: true
    },
    biography: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Также, к ней прилагается модель:

```js
export const Character = model<ICharacter>('Character', characterSchema);
```

Мне нужно вытащить из схемы значение `biography`, и поместить его в обьект, для вставки в PUG-код в виде обьекта, для последующего отображения на странице.

Мне предлагали разные решения, которые я не смог понять, как ими пользоваться, да и здесь нет части добавления `biography` в обьект.  Вот одно из них:

```js
let character = await Character.findOne();
character.biography;
```

PUG-код (модальное окно), куда и должно вставляться `biography`.

```
.modal-overlay
    .modal
        a.close-modal
        svg(viewbox='0 0 20 20')
            path()
            // close modal
        .modal-content
            | {{object.biography}}
```

Comment: Вы хотите взять из базы значения `biography` из всех возможных ключей в коллекции **Character** или из какого-то конкретного ключа?

Comment: Мне нужно взять конкретное значение из базы данных и вставить его в модальное окно. Но и нужно, чтобы обращение к ключу было глобальным, то есть, ко всем возможным biography. Поясню легче на деле. Сам проект - веб-игра, в которой игрок может вести свое biography. И сам игрок, нажав на кнопку в профиле другого игрока, выводит его biography на модальном окне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

по порядку.

- чтобы вытащить из коллекции определенный ключ (весь объект пользователя) из коллекции `Character`, Вам для начала нужно определиться по какому критерию (свойству объекта) Вы будете его искать в базе (по нику, по **id**, по чем угодно). после того как Вы определились, `mongoose` предоставляет Вам [много](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) способов как получить данные из БД. пример:

  ```
  const user = await Character.findById(userId); // где userId - это _id пользователя, которого запрашиваете
  ```

  или

  ```
  const user = await Character.findOne({ name: 'Petya' }); // где name - это имя персонажа, которого запрашиваете
  ```
- чтобы вставить полученного пользователя из БД в шаблон `pug`:

  ```
  res.render('index', { user: JSON.stringify(user) }); // это внутри Вашего контроллера
  ```

  после этого у Вашего шаблона должна быть переменная `user` с данными пользователя